# SQL syntax error on WHERE clause using Netbeans IDE / Derby

Tags: java, sql, syntax, where-clause, derby

the following line is the cause of the error, but I fail to spot where specifically it is wrong.

```
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT (SEATS - RESERVATIONS) AS AVAIL FROM RESERVATIONS "
                + " CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(FACULTY) WHERE FACULTY = ? AND DATE = ?) "
                + " WHERE SEATS = ?");
```

Followed by the error,

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "WHERE" at line 1, column 93.
at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
at ReservationEntry.reserveRoom(ReservationEntry.java:30)
```

Reservation Entry is the file that the prepared statement is in, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Comment: Your query does not make sense. Please show us sample data and expected results, along with an explanation of what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `FROM` clause! Some databases require them.  Something like this,perhaps:

```
SELECT (f.SEATS - r.RESERVATIONS) AS AVAIL
FROM RESERVATIONS R CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT COUNT(FACULTY) as SEATS
      FROM <table name goes here>
      WHERE FACULTY = ? AND DATE = ?
     ) F
WHERE SEATS = ?;
```

I doubt this does anything useful, though, other than fix the syntax errors.  You should ask a question with sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.